Spring: Images from file system are loaded very slowly when on VPS, faster on localhost
My / endpoint returns eleven DTOs, each DTO having a String field imagePath, which looks something like this http://localhost:8082/api/get_image/imagename.png (when on VPS, the imagePath looks like this: http://123.456.78.901/api/get_image/imagename.png).
Another endpoint /get_image returns an image with the provided name:
@GetMapping(value = "get_image/{name}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage(@PathVariable(name = "name") String name)  {
  ...
  byte[] image = this.fileService.getFile(fullPath);
  return image;
}

I use this method in my Spring code to load images from file system:
    public byte[] getFile(String path)  {
        try {
            File file = new File(path);

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
        } catch (IOException e)  {
            return null;
        }
    }

When I load the page with images, on localhost (my home PC, the folder with images is also located on the same PC), I get this result:

But when I deploy the same code on VPS (the folder with images is copied to the VPS computer as well), I get this:

The difference in speed is startling - 356 ms vs 11.13 s.
I hosted all eleven images on imgur website and made it so that the controller returns the DTOs with imgur links, rather than links that point to the controller's get_image endpoint.
Then the performance looks like this:


For some reason, there is still a difference, but a much smaller one and the VPS performance is much better.
Also after several refreshes, the localhost starts loading much faster, I assume due to browser cashing:

Which isn't the case with VPS.
I'm not sure what's going on here. Each image has size ranging from 1MB to 2MB. The dimensions of each image are 1456x816. I could potentially make each image smaller, but it appears wrong to me that loading mere 13MB of data would take that long, especially considering it's much faster on localhost.
